# How to delete items from range in array

Tags: javascript

I have 3800 items in array. I want to remove all the items after the 1500th. How can I accomplish that?

I tried using this

`arr.slice(1500,arr.length)` but it didn't work

Comment: `arr.splice(1500,arr.length)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: splice second argument is the number of items to delete. It's not a range. Omit second parameter to pick from start index (first argument) to end.

Answer (score 4):

`slice` creates new array. You need `splice` to mutate initial array.

But a simpler way would be to set `arr.length = 1500`

```js
const arr = new Array(15).fill(1);

console.log(arr.join(', '))

arr.length = 10

console.log(arr.join(', '))
```

Answer (score 2):

You either use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) assigning the result to the variable or use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
arr = arr.slice(1500,arr.length)
```

or

```
arr.splice(1500,arr.length)
```

The first one is "more functional", as it does not mutate the variable (you could assign the result to a different variable).

Answer (score 0):

[splice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/splice-method-array-javascript) will remove the items.

`arr.splice(1500, arr.length)`

Answer (score 0):

`slice` does not change the array which invokes it. You need to clone an arr or assign it selfs

```
arr = arr.slice(1500, arr.length)
```